# Delete entire row if 3 columns is duplicate and 1 column is blank

Tags: excel, vba

[image]I have 3 columns. I need to delete rows with duplicates based on column 1, 2, 3. If a row contains the same data from the other row but column 2 is blank, this will also be considered duplicate. Delete the row blank column 2 and retain row with complete data.

Highlighted in yellow are considered duplicates, Rows without data in column 2 must be deleted.

I'm stuck here.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("F:F")
    With Rng
       
        For i = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            If .Item(i) = "" Then
                
                .Item(i).CurrentRegion.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1,3,)
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `if cells(i,6)="" and (cells(i,4)=cells(i,7)=cells(i,8)) then rows(i).entirerow.delete`

Comment: `(cells(i,4)=cells(i,7)=cells(i,8))` returns false in VBA even if true. How about `If worksheetfunction.And(cells(i,6)="",cells(i,4)=cells(i,7),cells(i,7)=cells(i,8)) Then` ?

Comment: Thanks, both were good but the duplicates are still there. Do i still need to modify it further or just copy & paste the condition?

Comment: For the sake of data entry, might there be leading or ending spaces?  You may need to use `Trim()` to compare, if dealing with non-numeric values, e.g., `Trim(Cells(i,4).Value)` of "Hi " outputs "Hi".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Remove Duplicates If Blank Cell

- Some sample data and/or screenshots would have been gold for more people to understand what you're after.
- `RemoveDuplicates` cannot do what you desire.
- The relevant data are only the rows of the range whose cell in the `Blank Column` (`6` or `F`) is blank (`Empty`, `=""`, `'`,...).
- A duplicate is a row that has in a previous row had the same values in all the cells of the `Duplicate Columns` (`4, 7, 8` or `D, G, H`).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteDuplicatesIfBlank()
    
    Const dColsList As String = "D,G,H" ' Duplicate Columns List (2 at least)
    Const bCol As String = "F" ' Blank Column
    Const Delimiter As String = "||" ' Dictionary Delimiter
    
    ' Create a reference to the range ('rg').
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    ' Write the Duplicate columns to the Duplate Columns Array ('dCols').
    Dim dCols() As String: dCols = Split(dColsList, ",")
    Dim dUpper As Long: dUpper = UBound(dCols)
    
    ' Define the Dictionary ('dict').
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' ignore case i.e. A=a
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim drg As Range ' Delete Range
    Dim rrg As Range ' Current Row Range
    Dim n As Long ' Duplicate Column Counter
    Dim cString As String ' Current String (created from the Duplicate Columns)
    
    ' Loop through each row ('rrg') of the range.
    For Each rrg In rg.Rows
        ' Only consider the row if its Blank Column is blank.
        If Len(CStr(rrg.Columns(bCol).Value)) = 0 Then
            ' Concatenate the strings from the Duplicate Columns to 'cString'.
            cString = CStr(rrg.Columns(dCols(0)).Value) ' first
            For n = 1 To dUpper ' remainder
                cString = cString & Delimiter & CStr(rrg.Columns(dCols(n)))
            Next n
            If dict.Exists(cString) Then ' duplicate found
                ' Combine the Current Row Range into the Delete Range.
                If drg Is Nothing Then
                    Set drg = rrg
                Else
                    Set drg = Union(drg, rrg)
                End If
            Else ' not a duplicate, so add it to the Dictionary
                dict(cString) = Empty
            End If
        'Else ' The Blank Column is not blank: do nothing.
        End If
    Next rrg
    
    If drg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no duplicates found
    
    ' Delete the rows containing duplicates. Possible data to the right
    ' of the range will not be affected.
    drg.Delete ' for entire rows use drg.EntireRow.Delete
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed script. I follow the instruction but it seems like it still cannot find the duplicate rows. I have updated the description above to further explain my  rrequest. Thanks